# Turkey and Milk

Tags: kashrut-kosher

The rabbinic decree that chicken and milk dates back to the Talmud (Talmud, Chullin 113a). However turkey was not a known bird at this time. Why does this decree extend to prohibiting turkey and milk as well.

Comment: It's not chicken, it's any kosher bird

Answer (score 4):

The word used on page 113a of Chulin is the Hebrew "Oif" .

This word refers to the meat of any kosher bird that has wings/flies. (as Heshy pointed out)

The word used for chicken (and today as well) is "Tar-neh-gol-et".

Chicken is included in the general decree of Kosher bird meat. Therefore, if Turkey is a kosher bird, it is also included in the anti-milk/cheese combo decree.